# Tensorflow loss not converge

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am doing research on eye landmarks extraction. I have done some augmentations and normalization on the training data. But in the training phase, the error function doesn't seem to decrease.
The initial learning rate is set 1e-3 and will decay every 20 epochs and the batch size is 64. 
Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os


def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


class DataSet(object):
    def __init__(self, images, landmark, size, fake=False):
        if fake:
            self._num_examples = size
        else:
            assert images.shape[0] == landmark.shape[0], ("images.shape: %s landmark.shape: %s" % (images.shape, landmark.shape))
            self._num_examples = images.shape[0]

        self._images = np.asanyarray(images, dtype=np.float32)
        self._landmark = np.asanyarray(landmark, dtype=np.float32)
        self._epochs_completed = 0
        self._index_in_epoch = 0
        self.train = None
        self.test = None

    @property
    def images(self):
        return self._images

    @property
    def landmark(self):
        return self._landmark

    @property
    def num_examples(self):
        return self._num_examples

    @property
    def epochs_completed(self):
        return self._epochs_completed

    def get_next_batch(self, batch_size, fake=False):
        if fake:
            fake_image = [1.0 for _ in range(1024)]
            fake_landmark = [0.0] * 4
            return [fake_image for _ in range(batch_size)], [fake_landmark for _ in range(batch_size)]

        start = self._index_in_epoch
        self._index_in_epoch += batch_size
        if self._index_in_epoch > self._num_examples:
            self._epochs_completed += 1
            perm = np.arange(self._num_examples)
            np.random.shuffle(perm)
            self._images = self._images[perm]
            self._landmark = self._landmark[perm]

            start = 0
            self._index_in_epoch = batch_size
            assert batch_size <= self._num_examples
        end = self._index_in_epoch
        return self._images[start:end], self._landmark[start:end]


def read_data_sets(fake=False):
    empty = np.empty([0], dtype=np.float32)
    data_sets = DataSet(empty, empty, size=0, fake=False)
    if fake:
        data_sets.train = DataSet(empty, empty, size=0, fake=True)
        data_sets.test = DataSet(empty, empty, size=0, fake=True)
    print("reading training data...")
    train_dir = "train_imgs_aug.txt"
    f = open(train_dir, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    total_num = len(lines)
    lines = np.random.permutation(lines)
    VALIDATION_SIZE = 25000
    images_train = np.empty((VALIDATION_SIZE, 32, 32), dtype=np.float32)
    landmark_train = np.empty((VALIDATION_SIZE, 4), dtype=np.float32)

    count = 0
    for line in lines:
        content = line.split(" ")
        if not content: break

        img = cv2.imread(content[0], 0)
        images_train[count] = img / 255.0
        landmark_train[count] = [float(content[1]), float(content[2]), float(content[3]), float(content[4])]
        count += 1
        if count % 100 == 0:
            print(count)
        if count >= VALIDATION_SIZE:
            lines = lines[count:]
            break
    f.close()

    print("reading testing data...")
    VALIDATION_SIZE = total_num - VALIDATION_SIZE
    images_test = np.empty((VALIDATION_SIZE, 32, 32), dtype=np.float32)
    landmarks_test = np.empty((VALIDATION_SIZE, 4), dtype=np.float32)

    count = 0
    for line in lines:
        content = line.split(" ")
        if not content: break

        img = cv2.imread(content[0], 0)
        images_test[count] = img / 255.0

        landmarks_test[count] = [float(content[1]), float(content[2]), float(content[3]), float(content[4])]
        count += 1
        if count % 100 == 0:
            print(count)

    data_sets.train = DataSet(images_train, landmark_train, size=0, fake=False)
    data_sets.test = DataSet(images_test, landmarks_test, size=0, fake=False)

    print(data_sets.train.num_examples, data_sets.test.num_examples)
    return data_sets


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = read_data_sets(fake=False)
    print("Read data end!!\n")

    image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32, 32])
    landmarks = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 4])

    # paras
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, 16])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([16])

    # conv layer-1

    x_image = tf.reshape(image, [-1, 32, 32, 1])

    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    print(h_conv1.get_shape())
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
    print(h_pool1.get_shape())

    # conv layer-2
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, 16, 32])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([32])

    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    print(h_conv2.get_shape())
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
    print(h_pool2.get_shape())

    # conv layer-3
    W_conv3 = weight_variable([3, 3, 32, 64])
    b_conv3 = bias_variable([64])

    h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
    print(h_conv3.get_shape())
    h_pool3 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv3)
    print(h_pool3.get_shape())

    # dense
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([1024, 512])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([512])

    h_pool3_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool3, [-1, 1024])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool3_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    # dropout
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    # output-dense
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([512, 4])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([4])

    y_conv = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

    # training
    print(landmarks.get_shape())
    print(y_conv.get_shape())
    error = 1 / 2 * tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(landmarks, y_conv)) + 2 * tf.nn.l2_loss(W_fc2)
    # error = 1 / 2 * tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(landmarks - y_conv)) + 2 * tf.nn.l2_loss(W_fc2)
    lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float64)
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(error)

    train_name = "train(32)"
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(train_name)

    print("start Training...")

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            import re
            ckpt_name = os.path.basename(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            saver.restore(sess, os.path.join(train_name, ckpt_name))
            counter = int(next(re.finditer("(\d+)(?!.*\d)", ckpt_name)).group(0))
            print(" [*] Success to read {}".format(ckpt_name))
        else:
            counter = 0
            print(" [*] Failed to find a checkpoint")

        numberr = 0
        soll_EPOCH = 500
        EPOCH = 0
        learning_rate = 0.001

        for i in range(25000 * soll_EPOCH):
            image_, landmark_ = data.train.get_next_batch(64)
            error_data = sess.run(error, feed_dict={
                image: image_, landmarks: landmark_, keep_prob: 0.9, lr: learning_rate
            })

            if i % 25000 == 0:
                EPOCH += 1
                print("epoch:", EPOCH, ",training err :", error_data)

                test_image, test_landmark = data.test.get_next_batch(32)
                error_test = sess.run(error, feed_dict={
                    image: test_image, landmarks: test_landmark, keep_prob: 1, lr: learning_rate
                })
                print("landmark testing error :", error_test)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                print("early stopping")
                break
            if EPOCH % 20 == 0:
                learning_rate = learning_rate * 0.5
            numberr = i
        model_name = "model"
        checkpoint_dir = train_name

        if not os.path.exists(checkpoint_dir):
            os.makedirs(checkpoint_dir)
        print("total training count: ", counter+numberr)
        saver.save(sess, os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, model_name), global_step=counter + numberr)
```

and the output of the error value:

```
epoch: 1 ,training err : 16.404902
landmark testing error : 16.376444
epoch: 2 ,training err : 16.40308
landmark testing error : 16.361961
epoch: 3 ,training err : 16.43909
landmark testing error : 16.377134
epoch: 4 ,training err : 16.404552
landmark testing error : 16.370085
epoch: 5 ,training err : 16.433796
landmark testing error : 16.374432
epoch: 6 ,training err : 16.4025
landmark testing error : 16.362604
epoch: 7 ,training err : 16.378864
landmark testing error : 16.36681
epoch: 8 ,training err : 16.408669
landmark testing error : 16.37526
epoch: 9 ,training err : 16.414948
landmark testing error : 16.389187
epoch: 10 ,training err : 16.416836
landmark testing error : 16.373346
epoch: 11 ,training err : 16.429422
landmark testing error : 16.378914
epoch: 12 ,training err : 16.424402
landmark testing error : 16.357906
```

I sincerely hope some guy can help me out... 
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your l2_loss is way to high.

maybe try:

```
error =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(landmarks, y_conv)) + 0.01 * tf.nn.l2_loss(W_fc2)
```

Other than that you should consider using higher level APIs such as tf.layers it will save you a lot of work, will probably do some things better (like initialization) and will make your model much more readable

Comment: thank you for the rapid reply, you are right. I set the l2 norm coeff. too large that the gradient could not work. I have also check my training set that some values are over scale. It works now, thank you for your help